# Titanium run external Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, eval, titanium-mobile

I have a PHP file which returns some JS code like

```
var someVar= <script type="javascript"> some script..... </script><noscript> ......    </noscript>;
document.write(someVar);
```

which I have been able to get from a remote server using XHR Get, but am unable to load the same in to a webview, Have tried

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122643/load-external-javascript-titanium-mobile

and

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127598/evaljs-in-remote-webview

But I seem to be doing something wrong, either the eval function fails or nothing shows up.

I am able to get this working on a desktop browser by just adding the snippet

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="source.php"></script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to download a pure javascript file and then run it or are you trying to load a functional web page that works in a browser that either has a file with JavaScript in it or references another file with JavaScript in it?

Comment: It is a php file that generates js as described above

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in the onload, what is the response from the server?  It it sending an error message, the raw page or is it sending the content of the processed PHP?